# jQuery Mobile - page and same page id links

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Thanks in advance to sort out the problem...

Please find the following link ...
http://jsfiddle.net/yesvin/KrKvb/

and the code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jquery Mobile</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('ul.tabs-v, ul.tabs').each(function() {
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
                    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                    $active.addClass('ui-btn-active');
                    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

                    $links.not($active).each(function() {
                        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                    });

                    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                        //alert($(this));
                        $active.removeClass('ui-btn-active');
                        $content.hide();
                        $active = $(this);
                        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                        $active.addClass('ui-btn-active');

                        $content.show();

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" class="hea"  data-position="fixed">
                <h2>Header</h2>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div style="width: 20%; float: left;">
                    <ul class="tabs-v" data-role="listview">
                        <li><a href="#tab1"> <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/images/album-bb.jpg" /> <h3>Link 1</h3> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2"> <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/images/album-bb.jpg" /> <h3>Link 2</h3> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3"> <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/images/album-bb.jpg" /> <h3>Link 3</h3> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div style="width: 77%; float: right;">
                    <div id="tab1">Tab 1 Content</div>
                    <div id="tab2">Tab 2 Content</div>
                    <div id="tab3">Tab 3 Content</div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tab1">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>          
            </div>

        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

i had a jquery mobile tabbed template with header, footer, content left, right columns and nav bar. Here, the left column ul li working fine to show the tab content referenced by id using jquery function (ui-btn-active also works fine).

The same is not working in navbar component in jquery mobile/ or if it works current button is not replaced by ui-btn-active class.

Thus, i don't need to change the page for bottom navbar.

Can anyone help me to sort this out.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added `tabs` class to navbar `<ul class="tabs">` it worked on the first button only, plus contents are being shown.

Answer (score 1):

It will work this way, in fact, this is how it worked for me.

First, you have to add class **tabs** to `<ul>` of the **navbar**.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul class="tabs">
```

Then, copy ui-btn-active CSS styling.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-btn-active-custom { /* any name */
border:1px solid #2373a5;
background:#5393c5;
font-weight:bold;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px #3373a5;
text-decoration:none;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #5393c5 ),to( #6facd5 ));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient( #5393c5,#6facd5 );
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient( #5393c5,#6facd5 );
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient( #5393c5,#6facd5 );
background-image:-o-linear-gradient( #5393c5,#6facd5 );
background-image:linear-gradient( #5393c5,#6facd5 );
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}
</style>
```

In your JS code, replace all `ui-btn-active` with `ui-btn-active-custom`

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/KrKvb/7/

Comment: Hi OmarNew2php, Thanks for your reply!... It works fine.. But, can u please advice how do i state active class for both navigation.  (ie) If i click on the vertical nav button the selected button's active class should applied for the horizontal navigation also. How do i get it? Once again thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @Yesvinkumar I'm glad you have it worked. I'll work on that issue, hopefully I manage to help you out.

Comment: Hello Everyone... how do i state active class for both navigation. (ie) If i click on the vertical nav button the selected button's active class should be applied for the horizontal navigation also. How do i get it? Once again thank you very much for your advice.